What was the 6502's reset behaviour when the RDY pin was low
How does an original 6502 behave if the ready pin is being held during a reset/power-on event?

Would it pause CPU start-up entirely, delaying when some or all of the 6 internal cycles are executed? (the ones where it goes through the motions of preparing for an interrupt, except that the stack operations are hacked to be reads instead of writes)

Or would get past that and pause/loop the reading of the first byte of the reset vector?

Or would it only take effect once the CPU begins reading the first real opcode, looping the reading of that byte?


I'm particularly interested in how this situation would affect the data bus and address bus.

IIRC it will simply wait and repeat the first cycle.

From the "MCS6500 Microcomputer Family Hardware Manual (January 1976)" (p. 37)

The RDY input delays execution of any cycle during which the RDY line
is pulled low. This line should change during the Phase One clock
pulse. This change is then recognized during the next Phase Two pulse
to enable or disable the execution of the current internal machine
cycle. This execution normally occurs during the next Phase One clock;
timing is shown in Figure 1.13.
The primary purpose of the RDY line is to delay execution of a program
fetch cycle until data is available from memory. This has direct
application in prototype systems employing light-erasable PROMs or
EAROMs. Both of these devices have relatively slow access times and
require implementation of the RDY function if the processor is to
operate at full speed. Without the RDY function a reduction in the
frequency of the system clock would be necessary.
The RDY function will not stop the processor in a cycle in which a
WRITE operation is being performed. If the RDY line goes from high to
low during a WRITE cycle the processor will execute that cycle and
will then stop in the next READ cycle (R/W = 1).

I'd say, given that figure 1.13 (see below) shows R/W immediately going high at the start of the reset sequence and remaining high during the entire sequence (indicating a read cycle), this should apply to any cycle of the reset sequence. Since the expressed purpose of RDY = 0 is to inhibit any fetch cycles, this should mean that when RDY goes low, the current cycle is delayed (i.e., the progression of the clock to Phase 2 inhibited) and there should be no noticeable bus activity. Compare figure 1.13 below, showing no bus activity before Phase 2 goes low for the fetch of the reset vector. However, mind SYNC (6502 specific) going high during the 3rd cycle of the sequence. (I have no idea what the implications of RDY = 0 for this SYNC spike might be.)
(Notably, this is just my interpretation of the manual and not based on empirical data.)


I that sync cycle should only apere if RDY is already release. If pulled (again) during that cycle it would extend as long as pulled - see the right side of that graph.

@Raffzahn You're probably right, I also think SYNC should stay high when RDY goes low in this phase. But I wasn't sure about this and thought it may be something to be aware of…

Does anyone know experimentally whether the reset would keep reading the same address in the $01xx range while READY was low, or decrement each cycle?  The logic which handles SP updating on "push" operations would normally never have reason to care about the state of RDY, and there would generally be no downside to having SP get decremented on each cycle even if RDY is held low.

@supercat I think, the only variable here is that the NMI line is low (active). Notably, the interrupt sequence is asynchronous. However, I suppose, the cycle should be still halted before the fetch. But, again, no experimental data.
(Generally, this is a processor built to low cost, as opposed to what may be nice to have. So there shouldn't be much extra going on, in terms of special case. There's just "is it read or not", to cope with slow memory.)

% And, as stated in the manual, if it's not a write cycle, it's a read cycle (there are just these two states), so – in theory – the delay should apply. (Again, as for any statement in any manual, evidential data may diverge.) Also, as we fetch the vector, NMI is already high.

% And, finally, if the purpose of the RDY signal is to allow for synchronization with slow ROM, your ROM is still slow when the reset vector is fetched. So it would make sense to honor the signal here, as well. Otherwise, your ROM code wouldn't come out of reset and there's not much sense in having the RDY signal in the first  place…

@masswerk: I find myself curious whether the behavior of a PLA when SP equals $FC, which is stalled on access to $1FC, would be to read $FC while incrementing SP, repeatedly read and ignore $1FC as long as RDY is low, and then read and use the value at $1FD, or whether it would actually read $1FC while incrementing SP, then read and ignore $1FD while leaving SP alone, and then do one more read-and-ignore after RDY goes high, followed by the real access to $1FD.  From what I understand of the internals, the latter behavior would be slightly easier to implement, and is close enough...

...to the "expected" behavior of repeatedly accessing $1FC (but ignoring the result) that I'm not sure anyone would have noticed whether the address changed after the first access (since the value that was read would be ignored in any case, and I can think of no non-contrived situations where that could possibly matter).

@supercat, referring to the other half of fig. 1.13 (https://archive.org/details/mcs-6500-family-hardware-manual-1976-01/page/n47/mode/2up?view=theater), the read address should be put onto and remain on the bus. As I read this, this should be a continuous signal, as long as RDY is low. (Mind that as the reset vector is fetched we're already out of the startup sequence proper (initial 6 cycles), so the right side of the diagram should apply.)

@masswerk: I guess that still leaves the question, though, of whether the decrement of S would be stifled, since there's no other scenario where a decrement of S would need to be stifled.

@supercat: Mind that the bus access of a "push" instruction is a write cycle, so RDY would be ignored, For a "pull", as described, the read address should stay on A0-A15, until RDY goes high and the data bus is evaluated – and nothing going on else. Unless there's a bug… (There's always a possibility, as you can't just halt a 6502 like a Z80, as its internal state will degrade, and some internal clocking must still be going on. Which also seems to be, why there's RDY, at all.) I And, I've no idea, what a PLA may be making of this. (There seem to be a lot of edge cases, regarding timing.)

@masswerk: From what I understand, the internal state machine logic doesn't have a general means of keeping everything in the same state as it was at the start of the cycle, but instead distinguishes between e.g. "first attempt at opcode fetch/cleanup cycle", "repeated attempt at opcode fetch", etc. to prevent something like "ADC #2" from adding 2 to the accumulator repeatedly while RDY is held low during the fetch of the next opcode.  My impression is that the reason the 6502 only extends reads is that extending writes would have entailed adding additional logic, and...

...the main situation where I can see that being an issue would be with operations that perform stack pushes.  The only other write cycles during which any internal state would have reason to change are on read-modify-write operations, and specifying that RDY is ignored on the "wrong-value" write cycle would seem nicer than saying it's ignored on all writes.
